# Disconnecting control from BlockUIContainer

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I need to temporarily show some UIElement in FlowDocument. I encapsulate it in BlockUIContainer but I don't see how it can be disconnected from BlockUICOntainer when I don't need it anymore. There's no Remove method. Below code shows that - it ends with exception

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.'

E.g.

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
  <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb"/>
</Grid>

public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var c2 = new WrapPanel();
    // Imagine adding lots of controls into c2 ...
    rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(c2));

    var bc = (BlockUIContainer)c2.Parent;
    ((FlowDocument)(bc).Parent).Blocks.Remove(bc);

    Grid1.Children.Add(c2); // Exception. Here I want to move that c2 elsewhere in logical tree but I don't know how to disconnect it
        }
```

Sure, I could recreate c2 but that's not nice. Or I see I could call internal RemoveLogicalChild but that also seems hacky. How WPF expects this is done?

Thank you

Comment: There's not enough information in your post to provide a good answer. But it's clear enough that whatever's going on in the code, the main issue is that your design is fundamentally flawed. You should not need code-behind to manipulate the UI elements; there's probably a much better way to approach this from a MVVM perspective. But if you insist on this approach, you'll need to improve your question by providing a [mcve], a detailed explanation of what the code does and why, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: You have t o remove the UIElement. UIElement instances are only allowed to exist once in the visual tree. That's what the error means. When you add `c2` to the tree you have to remove it from the node before you can insert it at a different position. When talking about _"not nice"_  or _"that also seems hacky"_ consider to step away from your approach. You should handle the data that the UI elements are supposed to display and not the elements themselves. You generally should use a `DataTemplate` to create elements dynamically.

Comment: Since you didn't provide information about what you are doing, it's not possible to help. But it seems that the `Grid` is the wrong choice and should be replaced with a `ListBox`.

Comment: I have not downvoted your question, although I think it deserves it, since you are not providing enough information. You were told this already, but decided to ignore this. If you ask for help, then you must be willing to cooperate and accept that you are asked to provide more information. It is very arrogant to claim that people who are trying to help but ask for more information are just unable and dodging. What you are doing is wrong and shows a lack of skills.

Comment: This is no mean critic. Peter and me just offered to help you to improve your code, but decided to push us away. No reason to be rude or disrespectful.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I've concluded I don't want to be part of stackoverflow. I don't like such culture and it's just frustrating so for all parties it's better I am deleting my profile.

Comment: I really understand your frustration. But don't be too sensitive. Take it easy. I mean, nobody attacked or insulted you. I was just asking for more information so that I'm able to provide you a better solution. I just wanted to help.You somehow misunderstood my intention, thinking I am just trying to trip on you. I think you should've asked what information I need and then tell me that you don'Ät want a different solution. Just in a nice way.

Comment: But I follow you regarding the weird and annoying downvote culture of some people. Downvoting is generally a good thing, but it shouldn't be anonymous and only possible after leaving a comment. I will give you an upvote to compensate. But I hope you see your own wrong too (in your reaction - this is poison too). And I really mean it, don't take it too serious. Don't let this ruin your day. You received help. 20 views on this one, but only one downvote. Never mind. I think this place isn't too bad. Many people maybe most are nice people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly disconnect the element and its child elements from the visual tree. The XAML rules don't allow multiple references to `UIElemnts` in the tree. References are not tracked, which means there are no aliases of a single instance. Each `UIElement` element must be an individual instance.

You can decide to create new instances or properly clear the association:

```
var c2 = new WrapPanel();

rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(new BlockUIContainer(c2));

var bc = (BlockUIContainer) c2.Parent;
rtb.Document.Blocks.Remove(bc);

// Remove parent association
bc.Child = null;

// Update the subtree/template association
c2.UpdateLayout();

Grid1.Children.Add(c2);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for .Child property